# How to change RIDE (Robot Framework IDE) font settings

Tags: fonts, font-face, robotframework-ide

How to change RIDE (Robot Framework IDE) font settings?

The default font for the editor (tab 'Text Edit') and the 'Run' log (tab 'Run') is ugly (in my opinion). At least, a change of the default font and it's color presentation (font foreground/background), for both tab 'Text Edit' and 'Run' is highly appreciated.

I have Googled, but the suggestion given is only to change the 'Text Edit' tab color.

Comment: you can try to run this command in command prompt - "pip install  pygments"

Answer (score 1):

Two years later, we have improved Text Editor and Run tab to have background colors. Version 1.7.4 should have this working. You can try current beta version, 1.7.4b2. Install with: `pip install -U robotframework-ride==1.7.4b2`

Answer (score 0):

RIDE -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Text Font, click on edit.. and change the fontsize, close the window -> apply